# Sifr and Javascript changing stylesheets (without a page refresh)

Tags: sifr

I'm currently playing around with Sifr on my site. Basically I have some coloured blocks at the top of my page, which will change the stylesheets through javascript, depending on the colours you chose. I would like to know how I can get the Sifr h1/h2 tags to reload dynamically (no page refresh) onclick - if that's possible?

I've tried to add the sIRF.activate code in the onclick event and I've also tried putting the sIFR.activate code inside the set_style function, but to no avail. If anyone can help me that would be fantastic!!

Cheers Leanne

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given sIFR 3, it is possible to change some of the CSS used to render the text.

I'm assuming you have two replacements, for `h1` and `h2`, and we're only changing their color:

```
function changeColor(hexValue) {
  var css = '.sIFR-root { color: ' + hexValue + '; }';
  for (var i = 0; i < sIFR.replacements['h1'].length; i++) {
    sIFR.replacements['h1'][i].changeCSS(css);
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < sIFR.replacements['h2'].length; i++) {
    sIFR.replacements['h2'][i].changeCSS(css);
  }
}

// after switching stylesheet:
changeColor('#FF9900');
```

This should change the text color of the `<h1>` and `<h2>` replaced elements to orange.

The objects returned by `sIFR.replacements[][]` are [FlashInteractor](http://wiki.novemberborn.net/sifr3/FlashInteractor)s.

Comment: Thanks so much for the code, I removed the rollback function to use the one you suggested instead but I'm getting this error now:

Error: sIFR.replacements.h2 is undefined

I tried putting the code in the sifr-addons.js file, in the sifr.js file and also on the main page but still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used sifr myself, but I think your best bet is the [Rollback add-on](http://wiki.novemberborn.net/sifr/Add-ons). Then you should be able to effectively reload your sifr'd tags in your javascript by rolling back & then immediately "rolling forward" again by re-running your replacement statements (i.e. basically disabling & re-enabling it).

**EDIT:** Just noticed at the bottom of [this page](http://wiki.novemberborn.net/sifr3/JavaScript+Methods) there's a `redraw()` method... might actually be exactly what you're after? (again, sorry for the vagueness, but I've never directly used sifr myself)