# Making animation on sIFR3

Tags: sifr

Now I'm using sIFR3. It works very nicely.
Additionally, I would like to put an effect on sIFR.
My idea is that when the page loaded, sIFR(ed) texts change its color. For example, sIFR in list item change color one by one.
The purpose is to emphasize the sIFR(ed) texts.
Reading the document, I thought Flash filters are not for like this animation.
Do you think is it possible to make animation on sIFR ?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using JavaScript. See this answer for inspiration: [Sifr and Javascript changing stylesheets (without a page refresh)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754690/sifr-and-javascript-changing-stylesheets-without-a-page-refresh/758217#758217)

Comment: Thank you Mark.
The post is interesting. I'm going to try to make some Javascript.